# Javascript for loop suddenly breaks

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem.

I generate a list with all the elements with a specific class. After that i'm looping throug them to replace the class.

As you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/nafxLoLz/ only one of the 2 elements get replaced. The console.log clearly shows that the loop only goes through once.
If I comment the 7 javascript code out. (See the fiddle) the loop works fine.

What did I do wrong?

Code:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("default");
console.log(list.length);
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
  console.log(i);
  list[i].classList.add("red");
  list[i].classList.remove("default");
}
```

Comment: console.log(list) === twice the same div

Comment: Perhaps removing the "default" is causing the list length to be altered and hence the loop terminates. How about doing a loop in reverse?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a *live* node list. Removing the class from those elements removes them from the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` gets a **live** nodeList of all the elements with the class `default`, the nodeList updates as the elements change.

When you remove the class `default`, the length of the **live** nodeList changes, so when you start iterating at the start, for every element that has the class removed, the length decreases by `1`.

When you get halfway, you've changed half the elements, and you're half way in the loop, and the length is just half, so it stops.

The solution is to iteratte in reverse

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("default");

for(var i=list.length; i--;) {
  list[i].classList.add("red");
  list[i].classList.remove("default");
}
```

or get a **non-live** nodeList using `querySelectorAll`

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".default");
```

Comment: Darn, beat me to it. I would (personally) usually prefer a while loop though: `while (list.length > 0)`

Comment: @AlfredXing - a `while` loop works too in this case, but it requires a change that decreases the length, which in this case there is, as the class is removed. I've made it a habit to always iterate nodeLists in reverse with a `for` loop, that way it always work, regardless if you have "breaking" changes to the nodeList or not.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the array-like structure returned by `getElementsByClassName` is "live", that is, if it doesn't satisfy having that specified class, it gets removed from the array automatically.

The first run was caused by the first item. It gets a `red` class and removes the `default` class. The removal of `default` causes it to get removed from `list` automatically. Once your loop advances, index is `1` but now there's only 1 item in the list.

Comment: Wow, that's one of the most irritating things I've seen about JS DOM interaction in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding another class name to the squares that wont be removed, just to help identify them:

```
<div class="square default">
</div>
<div class="square default">
</div>
```

And use 'square' as the class selector:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("square");
console.log(list.length);
for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
{
  console.log(i);
  list[i].classList.add("red");
  list[i].classList.remove("default");
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle to demonstrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/nafxLoLz/1/